# Response.header giving null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

i am working on Angular 9.1.0  and .net core 3.0.100 in this i am getting null values in respone.header.get('pagination').

when i send call from my WebApi to postman show correct result that is[post man header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQEUX.png)

Here is the code of web Api `

```
 public static void AddApplicationError(this HttpResponse response, string message)
        {
            response.Headers.Add("Application-Error",message);
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Header","Application-Error");
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        }
        public static void AddPagination(this HttpResponse response, 
            int currentpage, int itemsPerPage, int totalItems, int totalpage)
        {
            var paginationHeader = new PaginationHeader(currentpage, itemsPerPage, totalItems, totalpage);
            var camelCaseFormetter = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            camelCaseFormetter.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            response.Headers.Add("pagination", 
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationHeader, camelCaseFormetter));
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Header", "Pagination");
        }`
```

it send correct result and Add in header.
In StartUp.Cs class i added 
 `services.AddCors();`
here is my usercontroller function
 `

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers([FromQuery]UserPrams userPrams)
        {
            var user = await _repo.GetUsers(userPrams);
            var userToReturn = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserForListDTO>>(user);
            Response.AddPagination(user.CurrentPage, user.PageSize, user.TotalCount, user.TotalPages);
            return Ok(userToReturn);
        }`
```

know when is send request from angular application it show null when values are present in header 
Here is the code of Angular

```
    getUsers(page?, itemsPerPage?): Observable<PaginatedResult<User[]>>
{
  const paginatedResult: PaginatedResult<User[]> = new PaginatedResult<User[]>();
  let params = new HttpParams();
  if (page != null && itemsPerPage != null)
  {
  params = params.append('pageNumber', page);
  params = params.append('pageSize', itemsPerPage);
}
  return this.http.get<User[]>(this.baseUrl + 'user', {observe: 'response', params })
  .pipe(
    map(response => {
      paginatedResult.result = response.body;
      if (response.headers.get('Pagination') != null)
      {
        paginatedResult.pagination = JSON.parse(response.headers.get('Pagination'));
      }
      return paginatedResult;
    })
  );
}
```

[Chrome Header image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQLJi.png)
please help

Comment: You have pagination in the backend and Pagination in Angular. First letter is different

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: it show null values

Comment: Debug and check the Headers object in angular

Comment: i debuged angular application as well as API application but i did not find where the problem is

Comment: @Harry response.headers.get('Pagination') = null this is the problem

Comment: Shouldn't it be this response.headers.get('pagination') based on your backend code and the response header screenshot...try that I think this should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Is your angular frontend application hosted on another domain? (CORS matters?) If true - maybe this can help:

1. I cant see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your postman response from API
2. By spec (rfc) header names are case insensitive. But angular implementation may differ from this spec, and probably it may match the `Access-Control-Expose-Header` by case only (make this value be consistent in response header name itself and `Access-Control-Expose-Header` to eliminate this possibility)

Comment: i set Access-Control-Allow-Origin but still same problem

Comment: Adjusting headers to be in same case everywhere - has no effect as well?